# Azure Databricks API: import entire directory with notebooks

Tags: azure-databricks

I need to import many notebooks (both Python and Scala) to Databricks using Databricks REST API 2.0

My source path (local machine) is `./db_code` and destination (Databricks workspace) is `/Users/dmitriy@kagarlickij.com`

I'm trying to build [2.0/workspace/import](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import) call, so my body is: `{ "content": "$SOURCES_PATH", "path": "$DESTINATION_PATH", "format": "SOURCE", "language": "SCALA", "overwrite": true }`

However I'm getting error: `Could not parse request object: Illegal character` and as per documentation `content` must be `The base64-encoded content`

Should I encode all notebooks to base64?

Maybe there're some examples of importing directory to Databricks using API?

Comment: Were you able to import the directory?

Answer (score 3):

After some research I've managed to get it work:

```bsh
Write-Output "Task: Create Databricks Directory Structure"
Get-ChildItem "$SOURCES_PATH" -Recurse -Directory |
Foreach-Object {
    $DIR = $_.FullName.split("$WORKDIR_PATH/")[1]
    $BODY = @{
        "path" = "$DESTINATION_PATH/$DIR"
    }
    $BODY_JSON = $BODY | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://$DATABRICKS_REGION.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/mkdirs" -Headers $HEADERS -Body $BODY_JSON | Out-Null
}

Write-Output "Task: Deploy Scala notebooks to Databricks"
Get-ChildItem "$SOURCES_PATH" -Recurse -Include *.scala |
Foreach-Object {
    $NOTEBOOK_NAME = $_.FullName.split("$WORKDIR_PATH/")[1]
    $NOTEBOOK_BASE64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$_"))
    $BODY = @{
        "content" = "$NOTEBOOK_BASE64"
        "path" = "$DESTINATION_PATH/$NOTEBOOK_NAME"
        "language" = "SCALA"
        "overwrite" = "true"
        "format" = "SOURCE"
    }
    $BODY_JSON = $BODY | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://$DATABRICKS_REGION.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/import" -Headers $HEADERS -Body $BODY_JSON | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the notebooks must be encoded to base64. You can use Powershell to achieve this. Try the below.

```
    $BinaryContents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$SOURCES_PATH")
    $EncodedContents = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($BinaryContents)
```

The body for the REST call would look like this.

```
{
    "format": "SOURCE",
    "content": "$EncodedContents",
    "path": "$DESTINATION_PATH",
    "overwrite": "true",
    "language": "Scala"
}
```

With respect to importing *whole* directories, you could loop through the files and folders in your local directory using Powershell and make a REST call for each notebook.

Comment: I did't find a way to encrypt the whole dir, command above give an well known error: "Access to the path '/Users/kagarlickij/Repos/databricks/db_code' is denied" and this is not related to filesystem but [System.IO.File] way of work

Comment: I ran the script locally on Windows Powershell and was able to import the files. Where were you running the script from? Anyway, glad you've solved it!

Comment: I'm running `$BinaryContents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("./db_code")` and getting `Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\Documents\databricks-ci-cd\db_code' is denied."` (filesystem permissions are ok)